# Class Initializer with @escaping parameter

Tags: swift, initialization

I'm setting up a class that can ideally store an async method for later use. I would like to pass a function inside of class initializer but I'm running into a weird compiler issue.

`Cannot convert value of type '(@escaping (Int) -> Void) -> ()' to expected argument type '((Int) -> Void) -> Void'`

If the method is not escaping/sync this works fine. The compiler also suggest to force cast the parameter `as! (((Int) -> Void) -> Void)`. Gave that a shot but it crashes.

Here's an example I've been messing with in a playground:

```swift
class NumberTwo {
    let numberTwoMethod: ((Int) -> Void) -> Void

    init(numberTwoMethod: @escaping ((Int) -> Void) -> Void) {
        self.numberTwoMethod = numberTwoMethod
    }

    func callNumberTwoMethod() {
        numberTwoMethod { myNum in
            print(myNum)
        }
    }
}

func getNumberTwoMethod(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        completion(2)
    }
}

func getNumberTwoMethodSync(completion: (Int) -> Void) {
    completion(2)
}

NumberTwo(numberTwoMethod: getNumberTwoMethod) // error: cannot convert value of type '(@escaping (Int) -> Void) -> ()' to expected argument type '((Int) -> Void) -> Void'
NumberTwo(numberTwoMethod: getNumberTwoMethodSync) // Works
```

Any suggestions on what's going on here or alternative ways of storing an async function as a variable in a class?

Comment: Please remove all useless parentheses, it makes eyes bleeding

Comment: Removed all the extra parentheses :,(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `@escaping` on the inner closure:

```
class NumberTwo {
    let numberTwoMethod: (@escaping (Int) -> Void) -> Void

    init(numberTwoMethod: @escaping (@escaping (Int) -> Void) -> Void) {
        self.numberTwoMethod = numberTwoMethod
    }

    func callNumberTwoMethod() {
        numberTwoMethod { myNum in
            print(myNum)
        }
    }
}
```

or slightly simplified:

```
class NumberTwo {
    typealias CompletionHandler = (Int) -> Void
    let numberTwoMethod: (@escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void

    init(numberTwoMethod: @escaping (@escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void) {
        self.numberTwoMethod = numberTwoMethod
    }

    func callNumberTwoMethod() {
        numberTwoMethod { myNum in
            print(myNum)
        }
    }
}
```

Also note this will probably create a memory leak since there is no `weak` anywhere.